# Python GUI class frames

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I made a programm, that works with frames to open new "pages". At line 135 I want to open a class, when `antmengen.get()==0` etc. But it's not working. I have no error, the new page just dont appear. How do I "open" the classes? Thanks.

```
        import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import *
    import random

    class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

            container= tk.Frame(self)
            container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
            container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
            container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

            self.frames={}
            for F in (fenster, auswahl, information1, information2, mode1, mode2, scale0, scale1):
                frame= F(container, self)
                self.frames[F]=frame
                frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

            self.show_frame(fenster)

        def show_frame(self, c):
            frame=self.frames[c]
            frame.tkraise()

    class fenster(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

            label=tk.Label(self, text="Das ist die Startseite")
            label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

            button=tk.Button(self, text="Start",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(auswahl))
            button.pack()

    class auswahl(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

            infbutton1=tk.Button(self, text="Information zu 1",
                                 command=lambda: controller.show_frame(information1))
            infbutton1.pack()

            infbutton2=tk.Button(self, text="Information zu 2",
                                 command=lambda: controller.show_frame(information2))
            infbutton2.pack()

            mode1button=tk.Button(self, text="Modus 1",
                                  command=lambda: controller.show_frame(mode1))
            mode1button.pack()

            mode2button=tk.Button(self, text="Modus 2",
                                  command=lambda: controller.show_frame(mode2))
            mode2button.pack()


    class information1(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            label=tk.Label(self, text="In diesem Modus gibt es 5 schon vorgegebene Antworten, die auf Ihre Fragen 'antworten'!")
            label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
            button=tk.Button(self, text="Zurück",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(auswahl))
            button.pack()

    class information2(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            label=tk.Label(self, text="In diesem Modus gibt es 5 schon vorgegebene Antworten, die auf Ihre Fragen 'antworten'!")
            label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
            button=tk.Button(self, text="Zurück",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(auswahl))
            button.pack()

    class mode1(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            label=tk.Label(self, text= "Stellen Sie eine beliebige Frage. Wenn Sie bereit sind drücken Sie auf 'OK'")   #Text1/Label für mode1
            label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
            def ok():
                a=random.randint(1,5)
                if a==1:
                    label=Label(text="Ja")            #Label antworten für mode1
                    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
                elif a==2:
                    label=Label(text="Nein")
                    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
                elif a==3:
                    label=Label(text="Vielleicht")
                    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
                elif a==4:
                    label=Label(text="Auf jeden Fall")
                    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
                elif a==5:
                    label=Label(text="Auf keinen Fall")
                    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

            okknopf=Button(self, text="OK", command=ok)  #Der ok-Knopf
            okknopf.pack()

            button=tk.Button(self, text="Zurück",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(auswahl))
            button.pack()

    class mode2(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

            label=Label(self, text="Suchen Sie sich aus, wie viele Wörter Sie haben möchten!")
            label.pack()

            def antmenge(self):
                mant["text"]="Mögliche Antworten: " \
                    + str(antmengen.get()) + " "

            mant=Label(self, text="Mögliche Antworten: 0 Wörter", width=25)
            mant.pack()

            antmengen=IntVar()
            antmengen.set(0)

            antm=Scale(self, width=20, length=200, orient="vertical", from_=0, to=1,
            resolution=1, tickinterval=10, label="Wörter", command=antmenge(self),
            variable=antmengen)
            antm.pack()

            button=tk.Button(self, text="Zurück",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(auswahl))
            button.pack()

            button1=tk.Button(self, text="Ok", command=antmenge(self))
            button1.pack()

            if antmengen.get()==0:
                    scale0(parent, controller)

            elif antmengen.get()==1:
                    scale1(parent, controller)

    class scale0(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            label=tk.Label(self, text="Es muss mindestens eine Antwort sein")
            label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
            button=tk.Button(self, text="Zurück",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(mode2))
            button.pack()

    class scale1(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, controller):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            label=tk.Label(self, text="Wort1")
            label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
            wort1auf=Entry(self)
            wort1auf.pack()
            def ok3():     
                a=random.randint(1,1)
                if a==1:
                    label2ant1=Label(self, text=" ")            #Label antworten für mode1
                    label2ant1.pack()
                    def wort1aufein():
                        label2ant1.configure(text=(wort1auf.get()))
                    wort1aufein()
            button1=Button(self, text="Antworten", command=ok3)
            button1.pack()

            button=tk.Button(self, text="Zurück",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(mode2))
            button.pack()


    if __name__== "__main__":
        app=SampleApp()
        app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Print `antmengen.get()` to see what you get.

Comment: Where is line 135 in this code ?

Comment: You can "open" class. You can create instance of class, or run function of some instance of class.

Comment: There is a rule: first letter of class name is uppercase - see `Label`,`Entry`, `Button` - it easer to recognise class in code

Answer (score 0):

I add `print` after `if antmengen.get()==0:` so I see that `if antmengen.get()==0:` is called at once after start program.

I think you have to redesign program because:

-

If I add `.grid()`

```
scale0(parent, controller).grid()
```

then I get this frame in frame with `Start` Button.

-

If I add `.pack()` and change `parent` into `self`

```
scale0(self, controller).pack()
```

then I get this frame in frame with `Scale` widget at once.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating the instance of the scale, but you aren't adding it to the window.

Take a look at this line:

```
if antmengen.get()==0:
    scale0(parent, controller)
```

Here you are creating an instance of `scale0`, which is a subclass of frame. However, you don't ever call `pack` or `grid` or `place` on this instance. Since other widgets in `parent` use grid, you should do something like this:

```
if antmengen.get()==0:
    s=scale0(parent, controller)
    s.grid(...)
```

It seems odd that you would create it as part of a class, but give it a parent widget other than the class, so maybe another bug is that the first argument should be `self` rather than `parent`. If you change the parent to `self` you need to switch from `grid` to `pack` since that is what the other widgets in the class use.